# Why use an extension method if you are able to modify the source?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Studying extension methods using the book as an example of expanding the functional structure of an `Int32` (`int` keyword) in C# (we cannot inherit structures and change the source code in the case of `Int32`), I realized that extension methods are needed for three things:

1. If inheritance is not possible, as in the case with sealed classes;
2. In case of the inability to change the source code;
3. If it is possible, but undesirable, to change the source code of a class or structure.

I wonder what would be a typical example for the third case.

---

#### The question:

When I describe the class myself and I can make changes to it, without using the extension method, but why in this case I might need to use the extension method if I can just change the code in my class?

That is, I ask you to give an example when I can change the code, but this is undesirable and desirable use extension method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do you use extension methods, ext. methods vs. inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787324/when-do-you-use-extension-methods-ext-methods-vs-inheritance)

Comment: I (again) doubt that this is a dupe; OP asks for a very specific case while the dupe addresses the general case and no answer addresses this specific scenario. Even more; OP already gives the answer to the general cases himself here, but wants to know more in-depth information about a specific case; @HenkHolterman.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I just stumbled upon a question where this might apply to.

You are wondering about the case of

> why extend if you can modify the source?

There are a lot of scenario's but the base line:

**You want to extend if the added functionality is not an intrinsic part of the class**

I'll give you an example

---

Lets say you have a API client. You created C# code to consume this client. Lets call it `WebClient`

Now, lets say you use this `WebClient` in another MVC Web API application to fetch remote data. This can be called by a remote user `A`.

There is a cass in which you'll end up with a situation in which you want to return a specific result to `A`, from your MVC Web API application based on the result of the `WebClient`.

This code will be used throughout the MVC Web API Application, so: considering [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you want to write it just once.

So, no you have the choice: in the `WebClient` or not.

Consider this:

---

The MVC Web API specific functionality is there due to the fact you choose that technology,  but it has nothing to do with the intrinsic properties and funtionality of the `WebClient`.

This would be a typical use case for extension.

See: [Duplication of code when on WEB Api validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598477/duplication-of-code-when-on-web-api-validation#comment105362317_59598477) as my source of inspiration.